# jQuery $.when() .then() not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

$.when() .then() is not working for me, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help. I want to make sure the form is loaded first then I want to populate a `<div>` inside the form to show Google's recaptcha. This is the test: It actually loads the form but the alerts are not poping up at all. I the test works I'll change the "alerts" to call the showRecaptcha function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function () {
    function showRecaptcha(element) {
           Recaptcha.create("publick_key_here", element, {
             theme: "red",
             callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field});
   };

  // load the form
  $.get('../php/formularioDeReserva.html', function (data) {
    $.when($('.subscriptionForm').html(data))
       .then(function(){alert('Then')})
       .fail(function(){alert( 'failed.' )});
    alert('I reached this point.');
  });

})
</script>
```

Note for **Felix**: My tests show that `.html(data)` is not done instantaneously. In the following code if I leave the `alert('Load was performed.')` the pause of the alert give some time so the `showRecaptcha` succeds. If I remove the alert nothing works.

```
$.get('../php/formularioDeReserva.html', function (data) {
        $('.subscriptionForm').html(data);
         alert('Load was performed.');
         showRecaptcha('recaptcha_div');
        });
```

Note for **Guiherme**: Trying what you suggested, which seems to me a good logical idea, still does not work, and I don't understand why not. In the following code the *subcritionForm* shows but the `success`, `error` and `complete` alerts do not pop up at all.

```
$.get('../php/formularioDeReserva.html', function (data) {
        $('.subscriptionForm').html(data);
         // alert('Load was performed.');
         // showRecaptcha('recaptcha_div');
    })
    .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Note: When did a "view source" I realized that the Java script was included twice because one of the file was not saving properly. That explained why the alerts were popping twice.

Comment: `$('.subcriptionForm').html(data)` will be instantaneous, there is no need of using `$.when` here. Just call the function afterwards. `$.when` only works for objects implementing the `promise` interface and which are actually changing their state. Calling animations will change the state of the jQuery object, but not setting HTML content.

Comment: My tests show that it is not instantaneous.

Comment: `$.when` takes `promise` as arguments, not jQuery objects. `.html` is synchronous and `alert` blocks the execution thread so please don't use it to debug-

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the

```
$.when()
```

before the

```
$.get()
```

but, if it just one get request, why don't use

```
$.ajax({...}).success(function(data){..}).error(function(){...})...;
```

or

```
   $.get({...})
    .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

even that, I think the fail() will never be call in that case.

Comment: As nifty delayed notation is, it always bugs me that you attach events after starting the AJAX (async) process.

Comment: I tried this too whith the `$.when()` before the `$.get`, but it seems that the `.then` is never run.

Answer (score 0):

**I gave up !!!**

I decided to rename the main `.html` file to `.php` and use an php include statement instead of the `.get`:

```
<div class="subscriptionForm"> 
     <?php include("../php/formularioDeReserva.html"); ?>
</div>
```

and changed the jQuery to a simple calling to show recaptcha:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
  function showRecaptcha(element) {
       Recaptcha.create("public key here", element, {
         theme: "red",
         callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field});
      };

 showRecaptcha('recaptcha_div');

 [..more here..]

});
```

Thanks all for your help.

**Update:** I have just realized that perhaps I needed to create a `deferral` and create a `promise`, but I don't really understand the concept and at the end it was easy just to use an php include.